# What kind of scribal abbreviation for Christi is this?

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations, paleography

These are the opening words of the ["Subtrahente se famula Christi Liudmila"](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Christianslegende.jpg) excerpt from Legenda Christiani (Vita et passio sancti Wenceslai et sanctae Ludmilae avae eius). However, what is the scribal abbreviation used for Christi here? The only thing I can read there is some unidentifiable symbol followed by "rpi" and I do not understand that.

[image: image of manuscript]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it is the [Christ monogram ΧΡ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Rho), followed by the  genetive ending *-i*. Those are not the  Latin letters X and P, but rather the Greek letters Chi and Rho, which are the first letters in the word ΧΡΙΣΤΟΣ (Christos). This is one of the oldest and most famous [Christograms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christogram), but usually the letters are on top of each other.

In this case they appear to have been written like Latin letters though.

The "unidentifiable symbol" is just a bit of the last *a* from *famula* colliding with the *x*.

Comment: You can find the abbreviation on page 12 of Cappelli's [*Elements of Abbreviation...*](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

This is Greek lettering for a Latin Genitive: christi.

There are three letters **xpi,** 'chi, rho, iota (or 'i');'
and a siglum (^)showing abbreviation.

The last letter of the *ablative* **famula** has tangled with the lower stroke of the 'chi.'